# Settings plugin not working properly with DateTime property

Tags: c#, xamarin, win-universal-app

I am using the [settings plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings) and I have it working to store some booleans. Now I wanted to add managing a DateTime object. I added the following to Settings.cs:

```
private const string TimeRemainingKey = "time_remaining";
private static readonly DateTime TimeRemainingDefault = DateTime.Now;

public static DateTime TimeRemaining
{
    get
    {
        return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(TimeRemainingKey, TimeRemainingDefault);
    }
    set
    {
        AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(TimeRemainingKey, value);
    }
}
```

Originally I used the following in my code:

```
Settings.TimeRemaining = new DateTime().AddMinutes(30);
```

When I added some logging I had this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
dt = dt.AddMinutes(30);
Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
Settings.TimeRemaining = dt;
Debug.WriteLine(Settings.TimeRemaining.ToString());
```

It prints out:

> 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
>
> 1/1/0001 12:30:00 AM
>
> 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Why does this behavior occur?

Comment: you have created a DateTime object but you have not initialized it with a value . So it takes the minimum DateTime value.

Comment: @Mainak that's not the issue here. He updates a Setting and when he reads it again, the updates are gone. Short version `Setting = dt` but afterwards `dt != Setting`.

Comment: What happens when you do:
`Settings.TimeRemaining = Settings.TimeRemaining.AddMinutes(30); System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Settings.TimeRemaining.ToString());`

Does it work then, or does the same error happen?

Comment: The Title of the question is misleading, DateTime.AddMinutes works perfectly as yourself demonstrated in the second writeline, what seems to be failing is the TimeRemaining property. Have you tried to use a different Default value in the AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault call to see if the problem is here?

Comment: What if you change the setter to `AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<DateTime>(TimeRemainingKey, value);`

Comment: @Draken nothing changes

Comment: @Doliveras I edited the title. I also tried changing the default value, but nothing changed. Since the new DateTime is actually saved.

Comment: @dotctor VS says the name can be simplified. No difference in output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The settings plugin [converts the DateTime to UTC](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/d4a45bad0fddd445c1178ab35fef38dd90ca812c/Settings/Refractored.Xam.Settings.WindowsPhone81/Settings.cs#L125) so it looks like in your timezone when it converts 1/1/0001 12:30:00 AM to UTC it gets 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM. As a result when the value is read back from settings you get 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

If you set the `Kind` for your date the plugin should work correctly:

```
Settings.TimeRemaining = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime().AddMinutes(30), DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: When using `DateTimeKind.Utc` it worked as expected. Thank you!